# Cannot find any provider supporting AES/CBC/ISO7816-4Padding in unit tests

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, security, spongycastle

I'm using SpongyCastle to support the transformation **AES/CBC/ISO7816-4Padding**. I have included the following dependencies in the *build.gradle* file of the Android project:

```
compile "com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.58.0.0"
compile "com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0"
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.58.0.0'
```

I do not have any problem to perform the crypto operations on an Android phone but I need the following unit test to pass (it is just a simple class where I have extracted the main functionality of an utility class I've got to encrypt and decrypt data so please ignore the hardcoded key and IV)

```
import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;

import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.Security;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class SpongyTests {

    static {
        Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
    }

    final static byte[] KEY = {
        0x2b, 0x7e, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, (byte) 0xae, (byte) 0xd2, (byte) 0xa6,
        (byte) 0xab, (byte) 0xf7, 0x15, (byte) 0x88, 0x09, (byte) 0xcf, 0x4f, 0x3c
    };

    final static byte[] IV = {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    };

    @Test
    public void testCryptoOperations() throws GeneralSecurityException {
        String plainData = "This is the confidential information";

        byte[] encryptedData = aesEncrypt(KEY, IV, plainData.getBytes());
        byte[] decryptedData = aesDecrypt(KEY, IV, encryptedData);

        assertEquals(plainData, new String(decryptedData));
    }

    public static byte[] aesEncrypt(byte[] key, byte[] iv, byte[] data) throws
        GeneralSecurityException {
        return symmetricCryptoOperation(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv, data);
    }

    public static byte[] aesDecrypt(byte[] key, byte[] iv, byte[] data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        return symmetricCryptoOperation(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv, data);
    }

    private static byte[] symmetricCryptoOperation(int mode, byte[] key, byte[] iv, byte[] data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/ISO7816-4Padding");
        cipher.init(mode, keySpec, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }
}
```

When I run the above unit test I receive the following exception:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting AES/CBC/ISO7816-4Padding

    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:540)
    at com.yoti.mobile.android.tags.common.SpongyTests.symmetricCryptoOperation(SpongyTests.java:49)
    at com.yoti.mobile.android.tags.common.SpongyTests.aesEncrypt(SpongyTests.java:40)
    at com.yoti.mobile.android.tags.common.SpongyTests.testCryptoOperations(SpongyTests.java:32)
```

As you can see I'm adding the BouncyCastleProvider in the first position but it does not work. Any idea about how I can make this test pass? :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this

```
static {
    Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
}
```

to this

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
}
```

Comment: I tried before that solution but it didn't work either :$

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It seems the SpongyCastle provider does not support that transformation. I had to add the following dependency for the test build:

```
testCompile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46'
```

After that the test worked! :)